# Slick 3.1, Left Joins and Filters

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I have a Slick query with two left joins (which end up as a `Rep[Option[...]]`) and column maps. I need to filter (using `like`) on the results. A row has to be included in the results if any of three columns match the `like` criteria, so I can't pre-filter the tables - I have to filter the resulting join, `Rep[Option]`s and all.

I can't figure how to filter the `Rep[Option[String]]` columns. The below code does not compile due to "cannot resolve symbol ||" - if compiles perfectly when I remove the `Rep[Option]` columns.

```
val joinedTable = Sites.map(s=>(s.id, s.gisId))
                       .joinLeft(SiteText.filter(_.lang==="jp").map(l=>(l.name, l.siteId))).on{ case(s,t)=>s._1===t._2 }
                       .joinLeft(SiteText.filter(_.lang==="en").map(l=>(l.name, l.siteId))).on{ case(st,t)=>st._1._1===t._2 }

val searchedTable = joinedTable.filter { row =>
  List(
    searchStr.map( t => row._1._1._2 like t ),
    searchStr.map( t => row._1._2.map(_._1 like t) ),
    searchStr.map( t => row._2.map(_._1 like t) )
  ).collect({case Some(criteria)  => criteria}).reduceLeftOption(_ || _).getOrElse(true: Rep[Boolean])
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to work for me:

```
joinedTable
  .filter({ case ((a, b), c) => List(
      searchStr.map(t => (a._2 like t)),
      searchStr.map(t => b.filter(_._1 like t).isDefined),
      searchStr.map(t => c.filter(_._1 like t).isDefined)
    )
    .flatten
    .reduceLeftOption(_ || _)
    .getOrElse(false: Rep[Boolean])
  })
```